# Python, trace undefined variables

Tags: python

in my program I have undefined variable somewhere:

```
global name 'cmd' is not defined
```

How can I pull out the line number where the variable is being used?

I know where the error is (cmd versus self.cmd).  The question is how to get the line number (or why it isnt shown).

Since I was catching error, I had to `traceback.print_exc()` to get line numbers

Comment: Can you simply search for it in your editor via ctrl + f or the equivalent of the editor you're using?  If it's telling you it is undefined then you probably don't have too many occurrences of it in your code right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where are you running your program? a Python stacktrace usually looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'cmd' is not defined
```

As you can see it indicates the line where the error is happening.

Comment: hmm, ok, i had `except Exception, e: print e`.  Why doesnt that print full stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

The traceback that results from this NameError being raised contains the line number which attempts to use the name. In this particular case, it seems likely that you forgot to import the 'cmd' module, but it's also possible you had a variable that was coincidentally named after a standard library module.